# Letting a function only be called using a macro

Tags: c

I am developing my own assert function in C, and is is declared in my header file as:

```
void Certify_Continuity( const char* expression, const int line, const char* file );
```

It should be called using a macro defined as:

```
#if !defined ( ENABLE_DEBUG ) || defined ( __CALLE__ )
#define DEBUG_ASSERT( e ) (void)(e)
#else
#define DEBUG_ASSERT( e ) ( e ) ? (void)0 : Certify_Continuity( #e, __LINE__, __FILE__ )
#endif
```

The problem here is that the programmers are able to call *Certify_Continuity* directly.

Is there any technique to disallow the user to call the function directly, allowing him only to call it using the macro?

Comment: Since a macro will simply make the preprocessor paste the corresponding code when it hits it, you can't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A macro is just textual (token) substitution performed before the compiler proper runs, so you can't prevent someone from just manually expanding the macro and removing the parts they don't like.

However, you can make it arbitrarily difficult and dangerous for someone to do this. For example, you can omit the declaration of `Certify_Continuity` from the header file, and just declare it inline like this:

```
#define DEBUG_ASSERT(e) do { \
    extern void Certify_Continuity( const char* expression, const int line, const char* file ); \
    if(!(e)) Certify_Continuity(#e, __LINE__, __FILE__); \
} while(0)
```

This way, anyone who calls the function directly has to declare the prototype first.

You can also name it in such a way that others will think twice about calling it:

```
void DO_NOT_CALL__USE_DEBUG_ASSERT__Certify_Continuity(...)
```

Of course, if someone is determined enough to bypass you, and doesn't care about the crazy wart sticking out of their code, then that's their problem. If they work for or alongside you, that's when you use externalities like code review to block this behaviour.

Comment: Or to paraphrase Marshall Cline: `// We'll fire you if you call this function directly. Use the DEBUG_ASSERT macro instead.`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the trick in C that `(foo)()` calls the function `foo`, whereas `foo()` expands the macro `foo` (under the assumption that both exists).

In you case, your macro should look like:

```
#if !defined ( ENABLE_DEBUG ) || defined ( __CALLE__ )
#define DEBUG_ASSERT( e ) (void)(e)
#else
#define DEBUG_ASSERT( e ) ( e ) ? (void)0 : (Certify_Continuity)( #e, __LINE__, __FILE__ )
#endif
#define Certify_Continuity(x,y,z) YOU_SHOULD_NOT_CALL_Certify_Continuity()
```

If the user tries to call `Certify_Continuity` directly, an error is issued that `YOU_SHOULD_NOT_CALL_Certify_Continuity` doesn't exist.

Of course, this can't prevent the user from calling it like `(Certify_Continuity)()`.